# Initialization of lasso path algorithm

Tags: lasso, algorithms

I'm trying to understand the LASSO-path algorithm that is described [here on page 9&10](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/sparsity.pdf) (*Sparsity and the Lasso* by Tibshirani & Wasserman, 2015).

First they say we initialize $\lambda_0 := \infty$,$s_A = A = \emptyset$. But I don't understand why we set $A = \emptyset$ as all the following computations involve $X_A$ which denotes the columns of the matrix $X$ whose indices are in $A$, which does not make sense if $A = \emptyset$.

Can anyone point out what I'm missing? / How this algorithm starts?

Answer (score 2):

The lasso (typically) does not penalize the intercept, and as the penalization parameter goes to infinity, the lasso model is an intercept-only model.

This is consistent with $X_\emptyset$ being a matrix that only contains this intercept. The algorithm starts with an intercept-only overall mean model. If you go through the other steps of the algorithm, you end up with the classical regularization paths of the parameter estimates, as in Figure 2 in the PDF, coming in from the right.

Comment: This specific version does not include a intercept parameter, but I just found the description below the figure you mentioned, where they describe how to choose $\lambda_1$, so that should work.